# How many elastic IP's do I need to host two sites using SSL in IIS on one windows EC2 instance

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

I have one windows instance on instance in EC2.
I have two websites configured in IIS on this instance, each with a different SSL certificate for two completely different domains. Each is a wild card but i feel this is probably irrelevant to my question.

I have configured two private IP's for the instance as per([this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/config-windows-multiple-ip.html))
Each of the sites in IIS is assigned a different IP.

My question is, 
Do i need to create two elastic IP's, one for each site, point the two dns entries their respective elastic IP's and associate each of them with the same instance.

Or is it possible to just have the one elastic IP, and have two private IP's for the instance and configure it in some other fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need 2 elastic IP's, one for each cert. [As per this response:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753045/why-would-one-need-two-elastic-ip-for-one-amazon-ec2-instance) Until SNI is fully supported, you need multiple IPs to do SSL based virtual hosting